# axWrapper want´s NpapiPluginModule::Default = module -- Where is "::Default" gone?

Tags: npapi, firebreath

Firebreath 1.6 -- VC2010 -- FBAXExample -- np_winmain.cpp

I try axWrapper and i got an error. Unknown NpapiPluginModule::Default

```
np_winmain.cpp
...

using namespace FB::Npapi;
FB::Npapi::NpapiPluginModule *module = NULL;

void initPluginModule()
{
    if (module == NULL) {
        module = new NpapiPluginModule();
        NpapiPluginModule::Default = module;
    }
}
```

NpapiPluginModule.h  older Version may26, 2010 i found. "static NpapiPluginModule *Default;"

```
namespace FB { namespace Npapi {

    class NpapiPluginModule
    {
    public:
        static NpapiPluginModule *Default;
        NpapiPluginModule();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a change to how the initialization works; remove np_winmain.cpp and dllmain.cpp from the project and it should work fine.

You know, rather than posting this on stackoverflow you could have just created an issue on the github project... I would have fixed it =] (still will, when I have a minute)

Comment: Thanks to @taxilian----Ok that fixed it. It takes a time to found another .html file then the default "/axWrapper/gen/FBControl.htm" (only a empty rectangle:the links don´t change the view). The test.html is for that. 2.) FBTestPrj.exe == "Component FBExampleCtl.ocx or one of its dependcies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid". Looking at this message i did not expect that this plugin is working in a Browser.

Comment: It was working when I last played with it, but that was awhile ago. I didn't write it.